# Javascript script works only once, unless developer tools are opened in chrome

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

My program is supposed to work like that: user fills the form and presses button, JS script reads the form into array and sends it to server with ajax, python server generates a picture with info from form, when done, JS uploades the picture.

The problem is the script works only once, unless I refresh the page (then again it works only once). It works as intended only with google-chrome developers tools opened. What could possibly be the reason for that?

js function:

```
function readSendLayers(ev) {
    (ev||event).preventDefault();
    var arr_layers = ['100', '50', '100'];
    var str_arr_layers = JSON.stringify({arr_layers: arr_layers});
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/layersPic',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(str_arr_layers),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function() {
            alert('Unexpected error');
        }
    }).done(function() {
        //change arch__pic with generated picture
        $("#arch__pic").attr("src", "../static/layer_pictures/0.png");
    });
};
```

python:

```
from drawTree import *
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/layersPic', methods=['POST'])
def layersPic():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        output = request.get_json()
        result = json.loads(output)
        drawTree(result['arr_layers'])
        return ("",204)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

UPDATE:
I added unique data to the picture's src and this seem to do the trick.

```
$("#arch__pic").attr("src", "../static/layer_pictures/0.png"+ '?' + (new Date()).getTime());
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? Is that all your JS? It's not reading any form data? You're also stringifying twice.

Comment: Console gives no errors. Only this: 
jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:5000/layersPic".
As for the JS code, i did not include the parts where data is being read from form into arr_layers variable as it seems to work fine.

Comment: `$("#arch__pic").attr("src", "../static/layer_pictures/0.png");` I guess, since the image you're generating has always same name / same path, it gets cached. The reason you can see it working with developer tools opened is the fact that devtools bypass cache.

Comment: as seen in this screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/ZShZR04/a.png

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to disable caching the picture in my script?

Comment: The `done` function appears to reference nothing from the result data.  What would you expect to change on subsequent calls?

Comment: I'm not sure this works in this scenario, but, could you please try adding a random query string to your pic's src? like: `attr("src", "../static/layer_pictures/0.png?94905402");`